# Find the Area bounded by $y=-x^2+4$, $y=x+2$

Tags: calculus

I set the two polynomials equal to each other and after multiplying everything by $-1$ I got $x^2+x-2=0$

My points of intersection are $x=1$ and $x=-2$

However, the graph of the polynomial is concave up. Why?

Comment: Doesn't setting the polynomials equal result in $-x^2-4=x+2,x^2+x+6=0$ which doesn't have solutions,i mean if you multiply with $-1$ then $x^2+4=-x-2,x^2+x+6=0$

Answer (score 2):

If you set them equal to each other you get $x^2+x+6$ which has no solution, so the two given functions do not intersect!

Comment: The OP did not solve the system of equations properly. $-x^2-4=x+2$ $\rightarrow$ $0=x^2+x+6$.

Comment: @Alex I made a mistake $y=-x^2+4$, $y=x+2$. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Update: Setting your new equations equal yields $x^2+x-2=0$, which factors as $(x+2)(x-1)$. Now, your intersection points are correct. Also, $-x^2+4>x+2$ from $-2$ to $1$. Now, take

$$\int_{-2}^{1} -x^2-4-(x+2) \mathrm{d}x= \frac{-39}{2}$$

Comment: @ zz20s I made a mistake $y=-x^2+4$, $y=x+2$. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + x - 2 = 0$ is not concave up or down, since there is no $y$ value.  It is merely a relation in $x$ only.

Comment: My question is then why is the graph not according to the value calculated when one is seeking to identify the points of intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks the area between $-x^2+4$ and $x+2$. The points of intersection are $x=-2,1$. The parabola is defined above the line on this interval. Integrate $-x^2+4$ over $[-2,1]$ and then subtract the area under the line over $[-2,1]$, which will require a second integration.